# Make Plot look like a Bloomberg Plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, bloomberg

I am trying to make a plot look like the ones of a Bloomberg terminal in R, and I found the following post for Mathematica:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48185/make-plot-look-like-bloomberg-terminal

My question is, can this be done in R I am thinking with ggplot2?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: `chartSeries(...)` in the `quantmod` package is designed to do this. It comes pretty close. If you're looking for the gradient fill below the price time series, then I don't think so.

Comment: yep. it can be done. `?theme` in an R console. consider adding what you make to `ggthemes`!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a first cut. It doesn't have gradient fill, and the closing price fill is a rectangle rather than a pointer to the graph (I tried `annotate` with `geom="segment"` to get an arrow background, but it looks like this doesn't work properly with dates). For general use it also needs some logic, rather than hard-coding, for deciding how much area to allocate for the closing price text at the right edge. I also haven't included a panel with high, low, average, etc., which can be added with `annotate`.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(199)
dat = data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2013/10/01"), as.Date("2013/12/31"), by="1 day"),
                 price = cumsum(rnorm(92, 0, 1)) + 100)

ggplot(dat, aes(date, y=price)) +
  geom_area(fill="navyblue", colour="white", alpha=0.5) +
  theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="black"),
        panel.background=element_rect(fill="#101040"),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major=element_line(linetype=2),
        axis.text=element_text(size=15, colour="white")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(min(dat$price) - 1, max(dat$price) + 1),
                  xlim=c(min(dat$date)-2, max(dat$date)+10)) +
  annotate("rect", xmin=max(dat$date) + 0.75, xmax=max(dat$date) + 7.25, 
           ymin=dat$price[dat$date==max(dat$date)] - 0.25, 
           ymax=dat$price[dat$date==max(dat$date)] + 0.25, fill="white", colour="black") +
  annotate("text", max(dat$date) + 1, dat$price[dat$date==max(dat$date)], 
           label=paste0("$", round(dat$price[dat$date==max(dat$date)],2)), 
           colour="black", hjust=0)
```

[image]